# Create-react-app console shows chunk files

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, source-maps, react-scripts

I would like to debug some errors happening during my React development. As you can see I can't see the source files. I am using create-react-app to create my project. I did not change anything else. Is this caused by webpack? It is happening in react-scripts start command. Thank you.
[image: Can't see source files.]