# How do show the actual line in chrome console (Errors tab messages)?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I saw two similar questions, which are still no one answer, I would want to raise this question again.

[Minified component stack trace in create-react-app (dev mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72535404/minified-component-stack-trace-in-create-react-app-dev-mode)

[Create-react-app console shows chunk files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485396/create-react-app-console-shows-chunk-files)

May I know how can display the actual line which causes the issue in the console? I tried to click the chunk.js file, which only redirects to the first line of its file.

Comment: There is an option to pretty-print the JS code, in the bottom left `{}`, https://www.canidev.tools/pretty-print-js.

Comment: @PankajParashar Do you mean the index.js? this file has already encoded like 'a, b, c,d'.

Comment: Can you provide a mininum example? It could be a bug in DevTools

Comment: @Jecfish You can refer the second link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485396/create-react-app-console-shows-chunk-files

Answer (score 0):

Try the pretty print option to beautify the `chunk.js` file, which would then jump to the line causing the error (see the GIF below). You might still see the uglified variable names, if no source map is available.

**More info:**
https://www.canidev.tools/pretty-print-js

[image]

Comment: I am fine in "info" Tab messages. I only get the problem in "errors" Tab messages.

Comment: It's the same step for any type of console message. What do you get when you prettify the code?